# Best Practices for Separating Content from Presentation in SQL

Tags: mysql, best-practices, concat, number-formatting

A common and useful paradigm of programming is to separate content and presentation. One system deals with building the result, another system deals with outputting it.

You see this with HTML vs CSS. HTML should ideally be clean and without any internal styling (color, position, etc), which should be handled by CSS.

I'm now wondering how this applies to SQL results. I often find myself formatting results in a query:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name,
    DATE_FORMAT(last_edit, '%d/%m/%Y') AS last_edit,
    CONCAT(
        record_type, 
        IF (private = 1, ' (Private)', ' (Public)')
    ) AS record_type
FROM people
ORDER BY updated DESC, LastEdit DESC
```

Three different scenarios are covered here:

1. The first column is a simple concatenation.
2. The second transforms the output into a different format.
3. The third actually adds content to the result.

I understand that there are many useful functions for transforming data in a query. But from a team development point of view, should I be formatting these results in the presentation layer rather than the logic layer (i.e., in my PHP code instead of the SQL query)?

If so, then how far should I take it? Are columns 1 and 2 acceptable but 3 isn't?

Is there a widely-accepted best practice regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  There is no one-size-fits-all answer.  Yes, a database is a persistent store for data -- focus on that when designing the schema.

Meanwhile, let me point out that

```
DATE_FORMAT(last_edit, '%d/%m/%Y') AS last_edit,
```

implies something that needs to be strongly stated:  Store the data in a generic format:

- Store Dates and times in the database in a format suitable to the database.  This may require conversion both during input and output.  It facilitates filtering and sorting (as in your example, the typos notwithstanding).
- Store text as UTF-8, not html-entites, latin1, etc.  This implies adding entities (or whatever) *after* `SELECTing` the data back out.
- Monetary values stored as `DECIMAL`; scientific as `FLOAT/DOUBLE`. etc.
- JSON can be handy for storing random attributes (think EAV) that don't need to be sorted/searched too much.

But, let's study a common example:  Should an "address" be split into `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `province`, `country`, `postal_code`.  Versus a directly printable `address`.

One rule for deciding is whether you will ever need to search/sort on individual pieces of the data.  Keep in mind that it is very hard and very inefficient to split apart fields for such purposes.

At the other extreme, would you even think about splitting up an image into pixels?  (I hope not.)

Now, back to your question.  Your example seems to have reasonable datatypes under the covers.  But your question is who does the formatting as it comes out.  You have given simple examples where it is quite simple to use SQL to do the formatting.  I would probably write it the way you did for a "simple" system.

If there is any chance of changing the formatting (eg, flipping and adding a comma: "last_name, first_name") you should *probably* leave that for later code.

For something more complex, it is better to postpone formatting.

Some things are messy in SQL, so it is better to leave for later code:

- Pivoting -- You have 2-dimensional data stored in 1D.  (Follow tag [pivot-table])
- Want to build tabular data but not duplicate the value (vertically) until it changes.  This is too cryptic to do in SQL; it is better to do in formatting code.

As for `IF (private = 1, ' (Private)', ' (Public)')`, consider switching from numeric to `ENUM('public', 'private')`.

Comment: Thank you, that's good information all around. **Format in the query for a simple system; format in the code for a complex one.** As for your final line, I'm hesitant to use `enum` as a user-visible descriptor because it brings language translation problems along with it (yes, i recognize my simple example does too). That last column was to demonstrate adding additional information to what is contained in the db. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @pbarney - Ah, multi-lingual.  That adds a wrinkle.  Sure, "1" could be the key.  Or, the ENUM could use 'private' which maps to '(Private)' in English.  You still have the lookup _and_ the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

that depends on what you want to do:

you can format your data in javascript/python/php, but as you do not want to change it or use it, you can format it in mysql,because you can directly display it, but as you can use the result set to calculate  and format everything you like.

If you need it to calculate some thing or other you can't format it, because you need to unformat it in the language you are working with, to use it. that also is truie for diplaying the same data in different manners for different people. so you don't need to change the query.

For eyample, when your server hardware is not the strongest, you can send the data, and let javascript do the the rest, because it runs on the user computer.

Conclusion, you have always put the effort to change the format, it doesn't matter where you are doing it, sompmy select the language, where you are most comfortable with and program it there.

with 5g and gigabit Ethernet, and quad cores and more cpus, it usually doesn't matter if you load a lot of data and let it calculate on the user device, but when you want to save bandwidth you would simply calculate everything on the server and let only the minimum be done by the user device or network.